# Firebase asynchronious data retrieval takes time

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I have a web app that uses firebase's method `onAuthStateChanged()` to subscribe to user data.
This functionality works fine and I love the subscribe functionality to get realtime updates on the data.

However, when displaying data, it always takes a while until my data is displayed -  makes sense if I call the function for the first time - data has eventually to be retrieved from the firebase servers.
But even when reloading the page or navigating to another component, data again takes a while to be displayed.
I am using `fb.data | async` to subscribe to the data in my HTML components.
Where `fb.data` is an observable returned in the `onAuthStateChanged()` block.

Not sure if that's just something to be prepared for when using front-end frameworks to retrieve data or if I actually am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A new listener is not going to be instantaneous.  Even reading from local disk cache is going to have a small delay.  There's not much you can do about this.

Comment: Thank you. In this case I will show a loading screen until all information is retrieved to improve usability. Otherwise it will be an incomplete screen in the beginning which is filling afterwards.

Comment: Yes, that's a common implementation.

Comment: Another related question that I'm curious about:Is there a specific reason why firebase uses front-end code (JavaScript) to do its job as opposed to e.g. a PHP backend in order to serve static content to the user? What are the pros/cons? An AJAX web-socket could still run and update the data if necessary right?

Comment: If you have a new question, you should post it separately. Though what you are asking now is rather broad in scope and might not be appropriate for Stack Overflow.